# Mysql stored procedure result is different when called from code

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework

I am using EF 6.0 and Mysql. My stored procedure is

```
delimiter $$
use ge_wv8g73$$
CREATE PROCEDURE Get_UserMapSelections(IN p_userId int)
BEGIN

SELECT @DefaultMap := ValueLong FROM userselections WHERE section = 'Last 
Selections' and userid = p_userId and Description like 'LastSelectedMapID';

SELECT CONCAT(

(SELECT IFNULL( 
@DefaultMap ,'0')
) ,',', (

SELECT ValueLong FROM userselections where section = 'Last Selections' and userid = p_userId
and Description like concat('MapPage', @DefaultMap)),',',(

SELECT ValueLong FROM userselections where section = 'Last Selections' and userid = p_userId
and Description like concat('MapRow', @DefaultMap)),',',(

SELECT ValueLong FROM userselections where section = 'Last Selections' and userid = p_userId
and Description like concat('MapCol', @DefaultMap))) as selections;

END$$
```

When i Call it in mysql workbench it returns different result

**59,147,8,579**

but when i call it through code using EF as follows the result is **59** only

**GE_Context.cs**

```
 public string Get_UserMapSelections(int userId)
    {
        StringBuilder spCommand = new StringBuilder();

        MySqlParameter[] mySqlParams = new MySqlParameter[] { new MySqlParameter("p_userId", userId)
                                                            };

        spCommand.Append("CALL Get_UserMapSelections(@p_userId);");

        try
        {
            return this.Database.SqlQuery<string>(spCommand.ToString(), mySqlParams).First();
        }
        catch { return null; }
    }
```

what could be the issue? Sometimes it has happened before when i used parameter name the same as field name in table e.g if had i used

```
select * from maps where userid = userid
```

but this is not the case here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your EF framework code:

> return this.Database.SqlQuery(spCommand.ToString(), mySqlParams).**First()**;

You are returning only **First** row. Hence you are getting only 1 result

Comment: my result is a comma separated list only with a single row and single column

Comment: you were right! my sp was returning two result sets while i was expecting only one. the second one was the correct one

Answer (score 0):

I would like to share what exactly i did.

So my stored procedure was returning two result sets which i did not notice, but at the same time only the first result set was being received in the code. So i could not do something like

```
return this.Database.SqlQuery<string>(spCommand.ToString(), mySqlParams).ElementAt(1);
```

I have changed my stored procedure as follows

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Get_UserMapSelections(IN p_userId int)
BEGIN

SET @DefaultMap := (SELECT ValueLong FROM userselections WHERE section = 'Last Selections' and userid = p_userId and Description like 'LastSelectedMapID');

SELECT CONCAT(

(SELECT IFNULL( 
@DefaultMap ,'0')
) ,',', (

SELECT ValueLong FROM userselections where section = 'Last Selections' and userid = p_userId
and Description like concat('MapPage', @DefaultMap)),',',(

SELECT ValueLong FROM userselections where section = 'Last Selections' and userid = p_userId
and Description like concat('MapRow', @DefaultMap)),',',(

SELECT ValueLong FROM userselections where section = 'Last Selections' and userid = p_userId
and Description like concat('MapCol', @DefaultMap))) as selections;

END$$
```

so it was a matter of adding parenthesis in the query and using SET instead of SELECT